# How to execute the command dialog and use its result in another function ? Focus cause ? Output cause?

Tags: bash, dialog, sh

How to execute `dialog` in a function, so that another function can use its result ?

```
function a(){

 echo IN A

      TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

      dialog --nocancel --no-lines --no-button --no-description --menu " -" 20 50 8 \
      `echo "$*" | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 ·/g'` 2>$TMPFILE
      clear
      cat $TMPFILE
}

function b(){

  echo IN B
  a $* | sed 's/\(.*\)/oo\1oo/g'
}

echo IN PROG
b $*
```

To execute it, I run :

```
./aaaa.sh ff1 dd2 ee33 ff66 ll11
```

And the result is the following. It doesn't display the dialog box, but there are many empty lines where it should have been.

```
IN PROG
IN B
ooIN Aoo

oo













ff1oo
```

I have tried to execute it with `$(a $*)` or `a $*` , but with no success

Comment: Doesn't dialog open a new screen and close it when it's done, so you'll just be left with the space from that screen when it's done. Pretty sure it works the same as if you use `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup`.

Comment: Good point. And why doesn't it open a new screen then close it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function "b" everything that is on standard output from "a" is sent to "sed". This means that both "dialog" and "cat" have their standard output redirected to "sed" which will break it in the current form.

Here is the fixed version:

```
function a(){
    echo IN A

    TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

      dialog --nocancel --no-lines --no-button --no-description --menu " -" 20 50 8 \
      `echo "$*" | sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\+\)/\1 ·/g'` >&2 2>$TMPFILE
      clear
      cat $TMPFILE
}

function b(){

  echo IN B
  a $* | sed 's/\(.*\)/oo\1oo/g'
}

echo IN PROG
b $*
```

The trick to make it work is to not have "dialog" standard output (the form) send to "sed" from function "b". To achieve that I redirected the standard output of "dialog" to same place as error output is at that time (let's call this the error screen) and then the error output is redirected to the file but this will not affect where the standard output was redirected to (error screen).

I also modified the reg-exp from sed because `echo "$*"` will output just one line and I thought you want to add a "." after each argument passed to the script not after all of them.

Comment: Thank you for this quality answer